# SassError: Undefined variable: "$bg-color"

Tags: reactjs, sass

I keep get this error no matter what I try:

```
SassError: Undefined variable: "$bg-color".
        on line 2 of src/scss/box.scss
>>   background: $bg-color;
```

To reproduce issue, type `npx create-react-app blahblah` then `npm install --save-dev node-sass`.

Here are the files I have

```
// ./src/App.js
import './scss/app.scss';
import Box from './Box';
const App = () => <Box />;
export default App;

// ./src/Box.js
import './scss/box.scss';
const Box = () => <div className="box"></div>;
export default Box;

// ./src/scss/app.scss
@import './_variables.scss';

// ./src/scss/_variables.scss
$bg-color: red;

// ./src/scss/box.scss
.box {
  background: $bg-color;
}
```

Then type `npm start` to see the error.

I've tried preceding all my scss file with underscores, no underscores, some have underscores and others do not etc....no matter what combination I use, i still get the undefined variable error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't  `box.scss` do `@import './_variables.scss'` ? Currently the variable are only imported in `app.scss`?

Comment: Ohh.. my intention was that because the parent component `App.js` imported `app.scss`, and `app.scss` imported a partial `_variables.scss`, that the variables be globally accessible.  If I have 100 other sub components, I want to avoid always writing `@import './_variables.scss'` in every sub component.  Im trying to adhere to the `DRY` principle.  is there a better way to achieve `DRY`?

Comment: What does your app.scss file look like? If you import box.scss in app.scss after variables.scss, do you still get the error?

Comment: Well you're already doing `import React from 'react'` in all your files right? ;)

Comment: Real answer: I don't know if there is a DRYer way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a variable to be available in a SCSS file, it needs to be either local, or directly imported.

Otherwise, and if you have global scope variable anyway, you could use CSS variables in the first place, to avoid imports.

In app.scss:

```css
body {
  --bg-color: red;
}
```

In other files

```css
.box {
   background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```